# OctoberCMS: How to show custom error message when unique constraint is violated?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

How can I replace the `"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'upload' for key` error message shown when a user tries to create a new model in the backend using `FormController` behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `unique` validation rule. See https://octobercms.com/docs/services/validation#rule-unique & https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique